# NuxtJS auth redirect after logout to various paths, if needed

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Did Google and read the documentation but no solution found yet, please suggest how to log out the user to different paths if needed.

**My scenario/issue**

- If a user is verified and logout, should be redirected to
  {domain}/login
- If a user updates phone number should be logged out
  and redirected to {domain}/verify to re-verify.

**Tried (not working)**

```js
this.$auth.logout()
this.$router.push('verify')
```

*I am always being redirected to {domain}/login :-(*

**Tried > still not working**
Disabled redirect for logout in `nuxt.config.js` as follows.

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/signin',
    logout: false,
    home: '/'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `verify.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
  auth: false,
}
</script>
```

And in your logout file

```js
await this.$auth.logout() // this one needs to be awaited
await this.$router.push('verify')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this may help

According to docs in https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/

> Each redirect path can be disabled by setting to false. Also you can
> disable all redirects by setting redirect to false

What I understand is you can make logout path to false in your plugin and push route wherever you want after logout.